# Acessing a PHP variable that is inside a HTML link. (First question btw)

Tags: php, html

I have the following line of code:
`echo "<p> <a href = change.php?id=$contact[id]>change stuff</a></p>";`

All i want to know is how to acess the attribute/variable "id" on "change.php".

Sorry if my grammar was confusing to understand.

Comment: You mean how to access it from change.php after the link is clicked? If so it would be in `$_GET["id"]`

Comment: Yes, that is what i wanted to do.

Comment: By the way, i tested what you said and it worked, thank you so much.